# Prevent users from having the same username

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have just found a pretty major vulnerability in my code while doing some testing,

Basically if my username was "admin" and password was say "12345"...
and a user joined with and chose the name "Admin" and the same password "12345"
when he/she goes to login they will be in my account on the website, As you can imagine I have created quite a flaw, as this would affect every potential user on the site.

So, my question is what can I change in this statement to make it check for an EXACT match.

```
   WHERE login_name ='$user' AND user_password ='$pass' LIMIT 1";
```

Heres the login_process.php file

```
    <?php
    require_once("includes/session.php");
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
    if(!$connection)
    {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("game", $connection);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $pass = sha1($pass);

    // Need to make a change to the below query, as it doesn't match for case sensitivity.

    $query = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_level FROM users WHERE login_name ='$user' AND user_password ='$pass' LIMIT 1";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $found_user['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $found_user['user_level'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "The username or password you entered was incorrect. <br/> Please click <a href='login.php'>Here</a> to try again.";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So you want protection against someone guessing your password?

Comment: No, the password isn't the issue(if it actually was 12345 it would be!!), Its that when the query is evaluated, it will accept "Admin" as the username when comparing it against "admin" in the users table.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want your queries to be case sensitive? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Yeah that would be the ideal solution, if it is at all possible.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the link!, By default my login_name row is "latin1_swedish_ci" which is case insensitive, By make a simple adjustment to the query " FROM users WHERE login_name COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE '$user' " it makes a case sensitive comparison. Thanks Heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default collation of database is case insensitive . so the user admin and Admin or adMin are the same. While creating user check the database whether same username already exist or not.

it seems that you are using case sensitive collation.. you can use case insensitive collation for that user table so that your query will work fine.

or

while creating user and checking the database for duplicate entry use `LCASE` function as follows

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LCASE(username) = 'admin'
```

Comment: Yeah, I have done that in my registration - to stop identical usernames being created. So what your saying is just make an adjustment to not allow any variant of a duplicate username?, eg aDmIn, adMIN etc

Comment: simply yes.. it would be easier if you show the user creating code

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will make some changes to the registration page to disallow users creating a variation of an existing username. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a UNIQUE constraint on your `login_name` column:

```
alter table users add constraint unique (login_name)
```

That should take care of any new entries that are added that only differ from existing entries by case (assuming of course that you're using the [default case insensitive collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html)). If you get complaints like

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'XXX' for key 'login_name'

then you already have duplicates and you'll need to clean those up before adding your UNIQUE constraint.