# PHP MYSQL Check Case When Querying Database

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive

How do I check the case of a string when querying the database? For example, with this statement:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
```

The value in the database is "Test". The user could, however, type in "test" and it would still work. How do I check the exact case? I've tried === and ==, but apparently they don't work in SQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537366/php-mysql-i-have-a-login-security-vulnerability

Answer (score 3):

Your collation needs to be case sensitive.

Change the collation of the username column to a case sensitive one.
For example if you are using latin characters only in the username column, then change it to `latin1_general_cs` or `latin7_general_cs`

```
ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `username` `username` VARCHAR( 500 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `username` `username` VARCHAR( 500 ) CHARACTER SET latin7 COLLATE latin7_general_cs NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

What SQL server are you using? Given that you're using PHP, I'm going to assume it's mysql and send you [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: his question makes it pretty clear he's using mysql :)  `mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");`

Answer (score -3):

Use the == operator to check the value of the database for example:

```
$row=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
while($rowData=mysql_fetch_assoc($row)) {/* fetch the value */
  if($rowData['value']=='test') {
    echo "yes value is correct";/* code for statement */
  }
}
```

Comment: and Maerlyn: He wants the comparison to be done in mySql, not in PHP. it makes no sense to get the value from mysql and then make a php comparison